# Filter a data frame by two time series

Tags: r, dataframe, time

Hi I am new to R and would like to know if there is a simple way to filter data over multiple dates.
I have a data which has dates from 07.03.2003 to 31.12.2016.
I need to split/ filter the data by multiple time series, as per below.

Dates require in new data frame:
07.03.2003 to 06/03/2005
**and**
01/01/2013 to 31/12/2016

i.e the new data frame should **not** include dates from 07/03/2005 to 31/12/2012

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the following data.frame with dates:

```
df <- data.frame( date = c(ymd("2017-02-02"),ymd("2016-02-02"),ymd("2014-02-01"),ymd("2012-01-01")))

        date
1 2017-02-02
2 2016-02-02
3 2014-02-01
4 2012-01-01
```

I can filter this for a range of dates using `lubridate::ymd` and `dplyr::between` and `dplyr::between`:

```
df1 <- filter(df, between(date, ymd("2017-01-01"), ymd("2017-03-01")))

        date
1 2017-02-02
```

Or:

```
df2 <- filter(df, between(date, ymd("2013-01-01"), ymd("2014-04-01")))

        date
1 2014-02-01
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `lubridate`. In particular

```
library(data.table)   
library(lubridate)

set.seed(555)#in order to be reproducible
N <- 1000#number of pseudonumbers to be generated

date1<-dmy("07-03-2003")
date2<-dmy("06-03-2005")
date3<-dmy("01-01-2013")
date4<-dmy("31-12-2016")
```

Creating data table with two columns (dates and numbers):

```
my_dt<-data.table(date_sample=c(sample(seq(date1, date4, by="day"), N),numeric_sample=sample(N,replace = F)))

> head(my_dt)
     date_sample   numeric_sample
1:  2007-04-11              2
2:  2006-04-20             71
3:  2007-12-20             46
4:  2016-05-23             78
5:  2011-10-07              5
6:  2003-09-10             47
```

Let's impose some cuts:

```
forbidden_dates<-interval(date2+1,date3-1)#create interval that dates should not fall in.

> forbidden_dates
[1] 2005-03-07 UTC--2012-12-31 UTC
test_date1<-dmy("08-03-2003")#should not fall in above range
test_date2<-dmy("08-03-2005")#should fall in above range
```

Therefore:

```
test_date1 %within% forbidden_dates
[1] FALSE
test_date2 %within% forbidden_dates
[1] TRUE
```

A good way of visualizing the cut:

## before

```
>plot(my_dt)
```

[image]

```
my_dt<-my_dt[!(date_sample %within% forbidden_dates)]#applying the temporal cut
```

## after

```
>plot(my_dt)
```

[image]